# MOD-10 Single-Digit BCD Down Timer Implementation in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have this code, but if I make load_data <= 9 after the reset, it counts 0, 9, 8, 7, ..., 0, 15, 14, 13... each clock cycle

I want it to count 0, 9, 8, 7, ... , 3, 2 ,1, 0, 9, 8, 7 ...

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counter is
  port (
    clock: in std_logic;
    reset: in std_logic;
    load_enable: in std_logic;
    load_data: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    output: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
  );
end;

architecture rtl of counter is
    signal count: unsigned(3 downto 0);
begin
    process (clock, reset) begin
        if reset = '1' then
            count <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clock) then
            if load_enable = '1' then
                count <= unsigned(load_data);
            else
                count <= count - 1;
            end if;
            output <= std_logic_vector(count);
        end if;
    end process;
end;
```

Here are the wave results using University VWF

[image: Countdown timer results]

Comment: How about putting a set condition when count = 0 ? a 4 bit value will underflow to xF when you do 0-1, so 15 is expected.

Comment: In addition to count not being assigned 9 when 0, output is assigned the value of count inside the elsif rising_edge (clock) condition, meaning output is an additional register.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, but the answer is obviously to load 9 when you get to 0.